# Can any MTB rear derailleur be mounted to a Scott type 1 MTB derailleur hanger?

Tags: derailleur-rear

Can any Shimano MTB rear derailleur be mounted to a type 1 (206375) Scott derailleur hanger.

I have a type 1 derailleur hanger with a Shimano STX rear derailleur mounted and like to mount a Shimano XT rear derailleur:

[image: derailleur hanger, rear/side]
[image: derailleur hanger, top]
[image: derailleur hanger, side]
[image: derailleur hanger, top/side]

The reason I ask is, because last year I wanted to temporarily replace my derailleur with a Shimano Alivio 8 speed derailleur because the old one was damaged, but I had problems mounting the derailleur in the correct position/angle. I was able to screw it tight, but only in a strage direction. I finally gave up and managed to repair my old derailleur faster then expected.

Now I'd like to upgrade to a 9 speed cassette, gearshift and rear derailleur and remembering that problem back then makes me ask the same question again.

Products in question:

- https://www.bike-components.de/en/Scott/Ausfallenden-Schaltaugen-p30245/ (type 1: last photo)
- https://www.bike-components.de/en/Shimano/XT-Schaltwerk-Shadow-RD-M772-9-fach-p16320/

Comment: Yes, the thread of the hanger is standard.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that RD-M772 for a frame with a standard hanger. It's one of the new Shimano models that have an extra hanger extension piece ("B-link") which weakens and destabilizes the attachment of the derailleur.  The idea is that you remove this piece when attaching the derailleur to a frame that incorporates a new type of hanger that points backwards, and then the derailleur is strongly mounted. Shimano calls that "direct mount", where "direct" sneakily refers to the fact that this adapter, which is necessary for attaching these derailleurs to a standard mount, can be removed.

Comment: Your old RD looks like a "vintage" Shimano STX RD-MC30. I'm guessing that you had been trying to temporarily replace it with the Alivio RD-M410.  That really should have worked; it's hard to guess what went wrong. (If you would care to try again and submit another question for troubleshooting, that would be interesting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread on a derailleur fixing bolt is typically 10mm x 1mm thread pitch.  For almost any standard derailleur, that will be correct.

There are a few very new designs on the market which might not fit, namely Shimano's new direct mount derailleur system, but that would be a special order in most shops at this stage.

Anything on the market for 9 speed mountain should fit a 10 x 1 thread.

So to answer your question:

Technically, no, not any derailleur will mount to your Scott derailleur hanger.

**As a practical matter, yes, you are pretty safe ordering any 9 speed MTB derailleur, and it will work.  And if it looks like the same mount, it will be.**

That said, it sounds like you may have cross threaded your derailleur hanger when you tried to change it the first time, so you may also want to pick up a spare derailleur hanger.